# How use AddressChanged event in CefSharp WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, chromium-embedded

I try to develop WebBrowser on c#, wpf and CefSharp for experience.
Use tabcontrol for tabs and TextBox for URL textbox.
I want, when address of page is changed, textboxurl was updated too.
So in CefSharp for WinForms i find AddressChanged event.
Like in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=itpEj1yB_Tg
But when i want use it with CefSharp WPF i cant use it.
So maybe i can add it by myself?
I find ChromiumWebBrowser.OnAddressChanged Method in APIDoc.
 http://cefsharp.github.io/api/51.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_Wpf_ChromiumWebBrowser_OnAddressChanged.htm

How can i use it?

Comment: Bind to the address property is the simplest way. Look at the Minimumexample project. Just search for CefSharp minimal example and you'll find it.

Comment: @amaitland i try search but cant find it. And cant do this by myself...

Comment: Don't give up so easily....